# How to retrieve specific column data from model bind show method?

Tags: laravel

I'm setting up a new project and want to retrieve data from passed model binding controller show method but output in show view is null

model :

```
class Content extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','body'];
}
```

this is my controller :

```
public function show(Content $content)
{
return view('content.show',compact('content'));
}
```

this is my index :

```
@foreach ($content as $item)
<td>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('Content.show',$item) }}">View</a> 
</td>
@endforeach
```

and this is show method that result is null:

```
<div class="card-header">
{{ $content->title }}
</div>
<div class="card-body">
{{ $content->body }}
</div>
<div class="card-footer">
{{ $content->created_at }}
/div>
```

i expect have result in show method because everything is okay but there isn't where is my problem ?

> Updated :

[dd($content)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwf2c.jpg)

Comment: is it returns any error..?

Comment: no it didn't return any value just blank page

Comment: can you put your route..?

Comment: check `dd($content);` in show method.

Comment: Route::resource('Content','ContentController'); i used resource

Comment: i updated my post for dd result

Comment: change in method parameter `public function show(Content $Content)`

Answer (score 0):

because you try to get $content while it is $item now :)

```
  <div class="card-header">
    {{ $item->title }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    {{ $item->body }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
    {{ $item->created_at }}
    </div>
```

Comment: but when i hit a tag then i redirect to controller show method and over there i pass $content to the view

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

I changed the route resource from resource('Content','ContentController') to

resource('content','ContentController') and the problem has been fixed !

i dont know why !

Answer (score 0):

```
//used to show a list, like what you are trying to do
public function index()
{
  $contents = Content::get();
return view('content.index',compact('contents'));
}
//used to show one item
public function show(Content $content)
{
return view('content.show',compact('content'));
}
```

What you have for you view works if you are looping over multiple content, otherwise you want:

````
    {{ $content->title }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    {{ $content->body }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
    {{ $content->created_at }}
    </div>```
````